# Capifony fails deploying

Tags: symfony, capifony

I'm using Capifony to deploy a symfony 2 application, but i got the following error :

```
executing "ln -nfs /home/mypath/shared/ /home/mypath/releases/20150902151722/"
servers: ["MY.IP.NU.BER"]
[MY.IP.NU.BER] executing command
** [out :: MY.IP.NU.BER] ln:
** [out :: MY.IP.NU.BER] target ‘/home/mypath/releases/20150902151722/’ is not a directory
** [out :: MY.IP.NU.BER] : No such file or directory
** [out :: MY.IP.NU.BER]
```

I have already run cap deploy:setup successfully.

Then Capifony rolls back after this error... What might cause this error ?

Answer (score 0):

You can debug your procedure deploy by launch the cap task as:

```
 cap -dv deploy
```

and, when the script ask you to execute the incriminated script, execute yourself on the server via another shell connected to the server (don't terminate the capifony script, take the task waiting meanwhile, otherwise it will rollback the execution without prompt you the error)

Hope this help

Comment: i get the following erro   [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
  There are no commands defined in the "assetic" namespace.       
  Did you mean this?                                              
      assets