# Deploying symfony project with capifony

Tags: ruby, symfony, capifony

I am getting the following error when I run Cap Deploy..

```
--> Creating cache directory................................✔
--> Creating symlinks for shared directories................✔
--> Creating symlinks for shared files......................✔
--> Downloading Composer....................................✔
--> Installing Composer dependencies........................✔
--> Dumping all assets to the filesystem....................✘
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
failed: "sh -c 'sh -c '\\''cd /var/www/html/test/releases/20160708103535 && php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug'\\'''" on dev.yarsha.com.np
```

My deploy.rb file

```
set :application, "Deploy Symfony Project"
set :domain,      "dev.yarsha.com.np"
set :deploy_to,   "/var/www/html/test"
set :app_path,    "app"

set :repository,  "git@gitlab.com:aswrgrg/demo.git"
set :scm,         :git
# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `subversion`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, or `none`

set :model_manager, "doctrine"
# Or: `propel`

role :web,        domain                         # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app,        domain, :primary => true       # This may be the same as your `Web` server

set  :keep_releases,  3
# set :deploy_via, :copy

set :dump_assetic_assets, true
set :use_composer, true
# set :update_vendors, true

set :shared_files,      ["app/config/parameters.yml"]
set :shared_children,     [app_path + "/logs", web_path + "/uploads", "vendor", app_path + "/sessions"]

set :branch, "master"
set :use_sudo, false
after "deploy:update", "deploy:cleanup"

set :user, "root"
set :password, "root.server"


# set :writable_dirs,       ["app/cache", "app/logs", "app/sessions"]
# set :webserver_user,      "www-data"
# set :permission_method,   :acl
# set :use_set_permissions, true

ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
default_run_options[:pty] = true

# Be more verbose by uncommenting the following line
# logger.level = Logger::MAX_LEVEL
```

Don't know what is causing the problem, I tried with different solution online and nothing is helping me. Can any one please help me solve my problem..

Comment: try this advice http://stackoverflow.com/a/32367462/2270041

Comment: @Matteo sorry that didnt help :(

Comment: check if assetic exist in your local env as console command and that is enabled in the prod  sf environment

Comment: For Capistrano 2.x you could try running it in debug mode (`-d`), this way it will ask whether you want to run the next command from the deploy script, and once you reach `assetic:dump`, just don't run it from cap and run it on the remote environment, so that you get all the debug output. This could help track the problem down.

Comment: @Matteo when I run